# cannot save target device as default in flutter device selector? Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, emulation

Does anyone know why I have 2 device selectors? And why I cannot save the target device as default in the flutter device selector? Android Studio.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu0y6.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily erase one of devices from AVD manager => last arrow => select delete.

But general the first device in list is the default one.

PS: You have to run device before you can use it!